# How do I reinstall torchvision and change it's version from 0.12.0+cu113 to only 0.12.0 in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, torch, torchvision

I was working on YOLOv7 custom model creation. But I strucked in runtime error and when searching to solution to it I founded this solution.

[https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/5511#issuecomment-1166336886][1]

But I don't know how to reinstall torchvision and change it's version from 0.12.0+cu113 to only 0.12.0.

Comment: did you try `pip install --force-reinstall torch==0.12.0`?